# array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string when using pushWoosh Class

Tags: php, arrays, class

I am having some trouble implementing the pushwoosh class http://astutech.github.io/PushWooshPHPLibrary/index.html. I have everything set up but i am getting an error with the array from the class.

This is the code i provied to the class:

```
<?php
require '../core/init.php';

//get values from the clientside
$sendID = $_POST['sendID'];
$memID = $_POST['memID'];

//get sender name
$qry = $users->userdata($memID);
$sendName = $qry['name'];

//get receiving token
$qry2 = $users->getTokenForPush($sendID);
$deviceToken = $qry2['token'];
//i have testet that $deviceToken actually returns the $deviceToken so thats not the problem

//this is the array that the php class requires.
$pushArray = array(
        'content'   => 'New message from ' . $sendName,
        'devices'   => $deviceToken,
);

$push->createMessage($pushArray, 'now', null);
?>
```

And this is the actually code for the createMessage() method

```
public function createMessage(array $pushes, $sendDate = 'now', $link = null, 

$ios_badges = 1)
{
// Get the config settings
$config = $this->config;
// Store the message data
$data = array(
'application' => $config['application'],
'username' => $config['username'],
'password' => $config['password']
);
// Loop through each push and add them to the notifications array
foreach ($pushes as $push) {
$pushData = array(
'send_date' => $sendDate,
'content' => $push['content'],
'ios_badges' => $ios_badges
);
// If a list of devices is specified, add that to the push data
if (array_key_exists('devices', $push)) {
$pushData['devices'] = $push['devices'];
}
// If a link is specified, add that to the push data
if ($link) {
$pushData['link'] = $link;
}
$data['notifications'][] = $pushData;
}
// Send the message
$response = $this->pwCall('createMessage', $data);
// Return a value
return $response;
}
}
```

Is there a bright mind out there that can tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, your are trying to if your are currently reading the `devices` sub-array. You should try this:

```
foreach ($pushes as $key => $push) {
    ...
    // If a list of devices is specified, add that to the push data
    if ($key == 'devices') {
        $pushData['devices'] = $push['devices'];
    }
```

You iterate over `$pushes`, which is `array('content' => ..., 'devices' => ...)`. You will first have `$key` = content, the `$key` = 'devices'.

Comment: Hmm im not shure if I understand you here. Do you mean to change the code in the pushWosh class? I have not made the class, and is just trying to implement it.
The documentation for the class can be found here. 

http://astutech.github.io/PushWooshPHPLibrary/class-PushWoosh.PushWoosh.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `createMessage` function expects an array of messages, but you are passing in one message directly. Try this instead:

```
$push->createMessage(array($pushArray), 'now', null);
```

Comment: This will work as long as you are always only going to send exactly one, which kind of makes doing the `foreach` not useful, though if that's what's needed and that's what the class is asking for then that's the way it is.

Comment: Thnx for the tip Wolfgang, this worked! Im still not recieving any push notifications on my device, but the error array message is gone:) Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The class is expecting an array of arrays; you are just providing an array.

You could do something like this

```
//this is the array that the php class requires.
$pushArrayData = array(
        'content'   => 'New message from ' . $sendName,
        'devices'   => $deviceToken,
);
$pushArray[] = $pushArrayData
```

Will you ever want to handle multiple messages? It makes a difference in how I would do it.